# Open a Subtab in Console For Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I know that there is workspaceAPI for aura development but I can't find anything in the web for lightning web component. Is there a way I can do this with LWC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well my colleague managed to look for a solution for this using the import NavigationMixin:

HTML:

```
<a onclick={navigateToRecordViewPage} data-id={*lookup id*}  target="_blank">{*lookup field*}</a>
```

JS:

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
add *** extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)
```

method:

```
    navigateToRecordViewPage(event) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: event.target.dataset.id,
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but how does it know you want to open the page in a subtab, and assuming it knows that a subtab under what parent tab? Is it focused when opened?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/get_started_supported_experiences) lwc does not currently support the lightning console .

Workaround is to use aura components and if you have an lwc , wrap inside the aura components. This way you can bubble up an event and let the aura wrapper open the subtab.

Comment: It's interesting how generally bad the "new" Salesforce tech is. The most basic actions are not implemented.

Comment: Less invasive refactor would be create "empty" (means not-displaying-anything) aura component, place it on page and set up communication with Lightning Message System to send info from LWC to open subtab.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
type: 'standard__webPage',
attributes: {
url: '/lightning/r/Custom_Object__c/'+recordId +'/view?ws='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname)
},
});

Thanks